# Windows 10 and Manjaro Cryptodisk error

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop, manjaro

Windows 10 is on C partition, Manjaro was in D but the D drive was formatted from within Windows.

I installed Manjaro on my Thinkpad. I choose an install along windows10 that was there already. I clicked to encrypt the Linux partiton in calameres. The partition that Manjaro was installed got deleted from with in Windows.

Now the problem is every time I boot up the machine:

> error: no such cryptodisk found
>   error disk 'cryptouuid/..................' not found.
>   Entering rescue mode...
>   grub rescue > _

I watched a few YouTube videos on repairing but non of them worked.

How can I fix this?

Thx,

DK

Comment: Are you asking how to delete/bypass grub so you just boot straight into Windows?  Method depends on your model and whether it is UEFI or Legacy BIOS so please edit question and add this info.

Answer (score 0):

So booting back to Windows depends on whether or not you have BIOS or UEFI firmware. However, if you have your Windows disk on you, then you can regenerate your BCD and boot into your installation again. First, try using Startup Repair from your Windows installation disk. That may or may not work. If not, go to a CMD with Ctrl-Shift-F10.

If you have a legacy BIOS, type in the two commands below.

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

And that should fix it.

However, if you have a UEFI machine, you need to use diskpart and mount your EFI partition. After that, you need to use the `bcdboot` command. I’ll assume you used X: as your drive letter for your EFI partition. Check the Microsoft docs for `bcdboot`and adjust the command below according to your needs:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s X: /f UEFI
```

That should solve it if your mobo is UEFI.

Comment: Thx, that fixed it.